# Adding code to specific part of my WordPress opt-in form

Tags: css, wordpress

Hi even though I have some experience with C# I have very little experience with any languages related to web development hence my question is probably going to seem very noobish.

I'm wanting to add an animated progress bar on my WordPress site for an opt-in form and I can't find any suitable plugins but I came across this CSS tutorial:
https://css-tricks.com/css3-progress-bars/

And downloaded its code example:

```
/*
     CSS-Tricks Example
     by Chris Coyier
     http://css-tricks.com
*/

* 
{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body { font: 14px Georgia, serif; }

article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup,
menu, nav, section { display: block; }

#page-wrap { width: 490px; margin: 80px auto; }

body { background: #333; text-align: center; color: #eee; font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, "Lucida Grande", sans-serif; }
h1 { font-size: 42px; font-weight: 600; margin: 0 0 30px 0; }

pre {
    background: black;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto 30px auto; 
}
```

Anyway my question is how can I add that code to a very specific place on my opt-in form if someone explains how I can add it on a specific part of a page hopefully I can figure it out from there.

I don't know what this code is classed as, as I know where to add CSS code for a page but now what this code does or where to put it exactly hopefully that all made sense.

Comment: Are you trying to do "multi-step" forms?

Comment: Not sure how that code sample would be useful for your question. There is code different from this in that page.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing or even what programming language it is I was hoping I could just paste the code somewhere and modify the size and color in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this to your HTML but you need to write a logic for increasing the width which is the progress bars percentage. You can write javascript for it.

```html
<div class="meter">
    <span style="width: 55%"></span>
</div>

<style> /* adding css here */
.meter { 
    height: 20px;  /* Can be anything */
    position: relative;
    background: #555;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.3);
}
.meter > span {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  background-color: rgb(43,194,83);
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    center bottom,
    rgb(43,194,83) 37%,
    rgb(84,240,84) 69%
  );
  box-shadow: 
    inset 0 2px 9px  rgba(255,255,255,0.3),
    inset 0 -2px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.meter > span:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(
    -45deg, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%, 
    transparent 25%, 
    transparent 50%, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%, 
    rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%, 
    transparent 75%, 
    transparent
  );
  z-index: 1;
  background-size: 50px 50px;
  animation: move 2s linear infinite;
  border-top-right-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
@keyframes move {
  0% {
    background-position: 0 0;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 50px 50px;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Good answer if it was for normal HTML, but he is asking to add it through WordPress.

Comment: Hi thanks I ran the code snippet here and it works but I've added it on my opt in form pop up using a custom HTML block but all it displays is the black border without the progress bar.

Comment: you are welcome :) can you mark the answer as "accepted"? if there is no progress bar CSS part might be the problem. <style> </style> part is CSS codes. can you add that part a different place in the page. if there is a CSS file you can add there too but just copy inside <style> </style>.

Comment: I still can't get it to work I added a HTML code element and put the code within <div> </div> and I put the css code in the style in a custom css section for the option page and now nothing appears and it says there's an error in the css area I pasted the code.